# Can I restrict batch account linked auto storage with Firewall and azure virtual network setting?

Tags: azure-storage, firewall, azure-virtual-network, azure-batch

I have batch account with auto storage linked where the application packages are stored. I want to restrict the access on the this batch linked auto storage with virtual network settings.
I tried adding vnet setting and allowed the subnet of my selfhost virtual machine scale set agents , from devops pipeline I am tryingto execute powershell script which uploads the application package to the batch account using below command

`New-AzBatchApplicationPackage -AccountName $BatchAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ApplicationId $ApplicationName -ApplicationVersion $newVersionNumber -Format zip -FilePath $PackageFilePath`

this command works when the storage network setting all networks is enabled, but when I try to select the selected network , the command files to upload the package with the error
`Failed to add application package DataExportProcessor version 89.0. The auto storage account keys are invalid, please sync auto storage keys.`

In the storage selected network I am allowing my devops scale set agent subnet but , I am not uploading package directly to the storage from scale set machine, the **New-AzBatchApplicationPackage** command uploads the application package to storage, but I am not sure which IP , I should whitelist in my storage account so that batch account can update the application package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **note** that, while setting firewall of storage account you need to select **`All Networks`** .

If you want to choose selected network, then you have to add your public IP address and the list of the IPs of the **BatchNodeManagement** to your Storage Account firewall.

To get the list of those IPs, you can refer this [**blog**](https://charotamine.medium.com/azure-security-batch-account-storage-account-2cdb07e37a18) by ***Amine Charot***.

**Make sure to add IPs like below:**

[image]

To resolve the ***"Failed to add application package DataExportProcessor version 89.0. The auto storage account keys are invalid, please sync auto storage keys"*** please check whether the keys in storage account and batch account are same or not.

If not sync like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Your Batch Account -> Storage Account -> SyncKeys***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Package deployment failures (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50a4d99d-4c65-4091-8320-eb835ea300f2/package-deployment-failures?forum=azurebatch)

Comment: Thanks, @Sridevi I tried the root cause mentioned in this  [Package deployment failures](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50a4d99d-4c65-4091-8320-eb835ea300f2/package-deployment-failures?forum=azurebatch)

Comment: after creating storage in different region and whitelisting the batch IP address I was able to upload the package from the portal, but from devops pipeline failed with the error **"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.NewApplicationPackageException: Failed to upload C:\a\r1\a/drop/DataExportProcessor.zip to Azure Storage. One or more errors Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation."**

Comment: Finally got this working now.
Created a storage account in separate region than batch account and added all the batch nodemanagement ip in the storage firewall 
created a private endpoint for blob service(by doing this I can upload the application package from devops using self hosted agent)